# Cannot get my image and frame height to match up

Tags: vba, excel

I have an image within a frame with a scrollbar on the frame.  I am having trouble getting the image and frame the same height.  It works perfectly, but I have this huge space at the bottom of my frame under the image.  Not sure how to fix this?

Hope this is enough info: userform =RejectSamples (H 606, W 708); Frame = Frame1 (H 540, W 684); Image = Image2 (H 800, W 612)

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
'Name of the frame
 With Me.Frame1
'This will create a vertical scrollbar
.ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical

'Change the values of 2 as Per your requirements
.ScrollHeight = .InsideHeight * 2
.ScrollWidth = .InsideWidth * 5
 End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: I figured it out, just had to adjust my

Comment: .ScrollHeight = .InsideHeight * 2.75